# How to get a static internal IP for a 4G modem using ModemManager and NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, network-manager, usb-modem, modem-manager

I have around 16 `EM160R-GL` 4G USB modems connected to one Ubuntu server, which I use `NetworkManager` to dial-up to the ISP.

The problem is that the network interface I am getting on my machine has an internal IP that is fetched from the ISP, and it keeps changing.

I am trying to set up some software that requires the modem's internal IP, so I would like to set up it so that the network interface gets a static IP.

What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: As you correctly identified, the modem gets its IP from the ISP and is, as expected, dynamic. There's no internal IP in this case unless your modem can act as a router. That seems NOT the case here.

Comment: When you are dealing with mobile network data, there is no way to get a static IP address. You can ask your ISP if they offer static IP addresses for extra fees.

Comment: @ChanganAuto is it possible to create another virtual interface with a static IP, and have it point to the modem network interface?

Comment: Your best bet is using an actual consumer grade router with USB port(s) that support USB modems.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thanks, actually, in this case, I am plugging around 16 of these modems into a server via a carrier board, so using a router unfortunately is not an option, I have to do it on the server itself. is there no way to do it at all? my best bet if this case is script I guess

Comment: Your title asks a question about A modem, and only now, in the comments, do you say "actually, it's 16 modems...". Your problem description-fu is weak.

Comment: Thanks, edited for clarification @waltinator